# How to plot data with two different timestamps in one plot?

Tags: gnuplot

I tried the following script, also i need add another url link with different time stamp format.

```
set grid
set xl "Time"
set yl "Temp(\260C)"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"
set format x "%H:%M\n%d/%m"
set multiplot layout 2, 1 title "MASER Temperature data" font ",10"
plot "<wget -q -O - http://hmtmp/~elab/MaserTemperature/temp/Feb05_2022.TEMP" using 2:6 w l title "Sensor-A", \
"<wget -q -O - http://hmtmp/~elab/MaserTemperature/temp/Feb05_2022.TEMP" using 2:10 w l title "Sensor-E", \
"<wget -q -O - http://hmtmp/~elab/MaserTemperature/temp/Feb05_2022.TEMP" using 2:15 w l title "Sensor-J"
pause 2
reread
```

[image]

Comment: Please follow the guide on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: time stamp of another url link is 04/02/2022 18:30:37

Comment: @THIRUKUMARANA Does the answer solve your problem? If yes, then please accept the answer, indicating that your questions is answered.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the older syntax where you set the input fimeformat via `set xdata time` and `set timefmt`.
You can also set the input timeformat individually in the plot command without `set xdata time`.
Check `help timecolumn`. Note that in the first case you have to plot column 5 and in the second case column 3 as y-values.

**Code:**

```
### two different input timeformats in the same plot
reset session

$Data1 <<EOD
Feb 28 18:30:37 2022    1
Mar 29 18:30:38 2022    2
Apr 30 18:30:39 2022    3
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
02/28/2022 18:30:37     2
03/29/2022 18:30:37     3
04/30/2022 18:30:37     4
EOD

set format x "%b %d\n%Y" time
set key top left

plot $Data1 u (timecolumn(1,"%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")):5 w lp pt 7 lc "red"  ti "Data1", \
     $Data2 u (timecolumn(1,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")):3 w lp pt 7 lc "blue" ti "Data2"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]